# Sequence value in data frame column

Tags: r

I need some help writing R

I need to check whether a specif column in a data frame has ascending ordered correctly.

e.g

```
df$id | df$order | df$any
  3        1         a
  4        2         a 
  7        3         b
  1        4         b
  2        6         a
  9        5         a   # select this row - out of sequence in df$order
  8        7         a
```

I would like to select the rows that don't follow the ascending sequence. In the example above, that would be the row with `df$id` equal to `9`, because in `df$order` the value `5` is found after the value `6`.

Obs. 1: in `df$order`, the numbers have range from 1 to N, where N is a number greater than 1.
Obs. 2: If possible I would like to use core libraries to solve the problem.

Any question, just ask on comments
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df[df$order < dplyr::lag(df$order), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Base R:

```
subset(df,c(0,diff(order))<0)
  id order any
6  9     5   a

subset(df,c(0,diff(order))>=0)
  id order any
1  3     1   a
2  4     2   a
3  7     3   b
4  1     4   b
5  2     6   a
7  8     7   a
```